# JQuery: добавить определенному словосочетанию в тексте тег span

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть следующая конструкция:

```
<div><h3 class="ItemTitle">Техника марки Bosch</h3></div> <div><h3 class="ItemTitle">Техника марки Hansa</h3></div> <div><h3 class="ItemTitle">Техника марки Indesit</h3></div>
```

Пытаюсь с помощью JQuery словосочетанию "Техника марки" в h3 заголовке добавить тег span следующим образом:

```
$('h3.ItemTitle').html($('h3.ItemTitle').html().replace('Техника марки', '<span>Техника марки</span>'));
```

Скрипт срабатывает, span к словосочетанию добавляется, но на выходе ВСЕ заголовки в коде становятся как первый т.е. вместо марок техники которые изначально в заголовках везде идет Bosch Получается вот так:

```
<div><h3 class="ItemTitle"><span>Техника марки</span>Bosch</h3></div> <div><h3 class="ItemTitle"><span>Техника марки</span>Bosch</h3></div> <div><h3 class="ItemTitle"><span>Техника марки</span>Bosch</h3></div>
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так в этом способе? 
Или подскажите другой способ, как можно реализовать данную задачу.

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Comment: Попробуйте вместо html().replace вставить foreach. А замену проводить уже внутри foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примените код "подмены" для каждого `h3.ItemTitle`. В противном случае, `$('h3.ItemTitle').html()` будет брать содержимое только из первого `h3.ItemTitle` и подставлять его в другие.

```js
$('h3.ItemTitle').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Техника марки', '<span>Техника марки</span>'));
});
```

```css
h3.ItemTitle span {
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="ItemTitle">Техника марки Bosch</h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="ItemTitle">Техника марки Hansa</h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="ItemTitle">Техника марки Indesit</h3>
</div>
```